# TYPO3 tt_news - show hidden news

Tags: typo3, tt-news

on TYPO3 with the tt_news extension, my contributors would like to previews news before publishing ; Problem : impossible to get a preview if the news is hidden. Our website is big and we can't display the news before to finish it, even for preview for a few seconds.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/4.0.0/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TsConfig/Index.html) :

> If a preview of hidden records needs to be allowed too, the checkbox
>   “Allow hidden records” needs to be checked in the plugin.

No way to find this checkbox.
Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Which TYPO3 news system are you using? You mention tt_news, but link to the documentation of tx_news.

Comment: Hi @sebkln - I'm using tt_news.

Comment: please provide some version numbers: which TYPO3/ which tt_news do you use?

Comment: I created an issue for this in the tt_news project on github: https://github.com/rupertgermann/tt_news/issues/102 That way you won't get a solution right now, but your request seems quite useful to me. If you subscribe to the issue, you will get notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [tt_news documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/Manual/Index.html?highlight=preview#include-static-extension-templates), you have to set the following **Page TSconfig**:

```
tx_ttnews.singlePid = 37
```

where `37` is the UID of the page containing the single view plugin.

Apparently this functionality is currently broken:

- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/67304
- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75768

The second issue on forge.typo3.org provides a possible solution which should work in general with all records of any extension (TYPO3 v7 and above!). Again, **Page TSconfig** (no TypoScript):

```
TCEMAIN.preview {
    tt_news {
        previewPageId = 37
        useDefaultLanguageRecord = 0
        fieldToParameterMap {
            uid = tx_ttnews[tt_news]
        }
    }
}
```

I successfully tested this in TYPO3 v7. One major drawback – as already noted in your question – is that this does not work with hidden records.

Previewing hidden records result in the error message

> no news_id given

*Edit:* As Bernd suggested, you could make use of categories to hide drafts of news records and use the preview solution above:

1. If you already use news categories: Set the *category mode* in the list view plugin(s) of tt_news to hide news records which do not own the desired categories. Let the editors assign the categories only if the content is ready.
2. Otherwise: use a new category *preview* – as Bernd suggested – and hide records with this category in the list view plugin.

The latter is a bit more risky to use for editors, as they could forget to set this temporary category. Nonetheless, you as an integrator could use the TSconfig `TCAdefaults` to automatically assign this *preview* category to all new records. The editors would only have to remove the category when the news record is completed.

Another possible workaround could be to save drafts in a separate folder which is not used by the list view plugin of tt_news. Then you also could use the preview solution above.

---

If that's not the right way of working for you or your editors, you could try using the [workspaces extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/workspaces/7.6/Administration/Workspaces/Index.html) which ships with the TYPO3 core.

Comment: Thanks for the help. At the end there is no perfect solution and the best way is to tell my contributors to hide/unhide the news, because alternatives are more complicated. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

a clean solution would be the usage of workspaces. but not all extension support  it.

so another option would be to simulate workspaces:
build a page where your news can be seen and secure it with a login. so if only the new records should be shown you might create a 'preview' category, which is shown only on the special preview page.

Comment: Hello Bernd, it's too complicated for newbie contributors. I'm gonna tell them to hide/unhide the news in the production environment beacause it's the simpliest solution.